# Dotfuscator XamarinForms: command exited with code 1

Tags: xamarin.forms, dotfuscator

while running Dotfuscator to obfuscate xamarin application, I'm getting the following error.

[image]

Any help on this?

FYI : I refered, the below link
https://www.preemptive.com/blog/article/874-using-dotfuscator-community-edition-with-xamarin/91-dotfuscator-ce

Comment: Images of text are discouraged. Formatted text is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get more information from Visual Studio's build output tab. If you have the MSBuild verbosity dialed up as described in the blog, Dotfuscator's console output will be there. It should explain the reason for the exit code.

Comment: This is the error " Project.Droid.csproj is already open as a project or a solution and cannot be opened in an editor at this time."
But, I havent opened *.csproj file" other than the solution which i'm trying to execute.

Comment: That error message is from Visual Studio itself, not from Dotfuscator. (Dotfuscator doesn't do anything with csproj files.) It's the message you get if you try to open a csproj file in the VS code editor if you already have it loaded as a project. I'm not sure why you are getting that at build time.